# Code that can be used to iterate over every control on all reports in a Microsoft Access database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, vsto

Can anyone suggest c# code that can be used to iterate over every control on all reports in a Microsoft Access database? The reason for doing this is that I am converting reports from Microsoft Access to Reporting Services and I want to find all reports in access that has specific text in the control source property.

Currently I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access assemblies but the code I am using is not working. This is because Access API knowledge is  limited.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           OpenDatabase();
           DisplayReportElements();
           Console.ReadLine();
    }
private static void OpenDatabase()
    {
        app = new Application();
        app.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"database.mdb");
        app.Visible = false;
        //app.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\DLDWorkspace\Truama\Skills Training.mdb");
    }

public static void DisplayReportElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < app.CurrentProject.AllReports.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Report report = app.Reports[i];
            foreach (Control control in report.Controls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", report.FormName, control.Name);
                ControlProperties(control);
            }
        }
    }
```

The following code produces an exception with the message "The number you used to refer to the report is invalid." on line Report report = app.Reports[i];. To get around this I go through and Open each report by calling  app.DoCmd.OpenReport in a loop. There is two problems with this.  1. It takes over 12 hours to process 300 reports. and 2. after about 300 (of 600) reports I get an Index is out of bounds somewhere in DisplayReportElements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through the reports and their controls from within an `Access.Application` your approach is correct. If you find that process to be too slow or otherwise troublesome then an alternative approach would be to dump all of the reports to text files using the `Application.SaveAsText` method ...

```csharp
var app = new Application();
app.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
for (int i = 0; i < app.CurrentProject.AllReports.Count; i++)
{
    string rptName = app.CurrentProject.AllReports[i].Name;
    Console.WriteLine("Dumping [{0}] ...", rptName);
    string fileSpec = @"C:\__tmp\ReportDump\" + rptName + ".txt";
    app.SaveAsText(AcObjectType.acReport, rptName, fileSpec);
}
app.CloseCurrentDatabase();
app.Quit();
```

and then use your favorite text-searching tool to scan the files for lines that contain 'ControlSource =' followed by the string you want to find, e.g.,

```
        ControlSource ="LastName"
```